# Проблемы в локализации закрытия вопросов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов

1. Не локализована пометка closed/duplicate/migrated в результатах поиска

> [image: bug]

---

2. Неправильный перевод сообщения об ошибке при попытке закрыть вопрос дубликатом к неотвеченному вопросу:

> Данный вопрос не имеет ответа, получившего голос «за» или «против»

Английский текст:

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

Должно быть:

> Данный вопрос не имеет ответа с положительным рейтингом или принятого ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Строки перевёл
2. Предложенный перевод немного модифицировал:

   > Вопрос не имеет принятого ответа или ответа с положительным рейтингом